# Imagem armazenada no banco não está sendo exibida na View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, imagem

Estou tentando exibir uma imagem que está armazenada no banco de dados. Quando o campo Foto (do tipo Image) da tabela está nulo, eu exibo uma imagem padrão que está armazenada no diretório. O problema é que as imagens que vem do banco não estão sendo exibidas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A Action que está exibindo fazendo o tratamento está abaixo:

```
[HttpGet]
        public FileContentResult ShowFoto(int? id)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = null;
            string fileType = null;

            try
            {
                var terapeuta = db.TERAPEUTAs.Find(id); // Busca a imagem no Banco
                if (terapeuta != null)
                {
                    if (terapeuta.FOTO != null)
                    {
                        fileBytes = terapeuta.FOTO; // do tipo byte[]
                        fileType = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.ToString(); // Tipo da Foto
                        return File(fileBytes, fileType);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/SemFoto.jpg"));
                        return File(imageToByteArray(img), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/SemFoto.jpg"));
                    return File(imageToByteArray(img), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

O código da View para exibição da imagem está abaixo:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "Terapeutas", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "form1", @name = "form1" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        foreach (var item in Model.Terapeutas)
        {
            <img src="/Terapeutas/ShowFoto?id=@item.ID_TERAPEUTA" class="img-circle" alt="Foto Terapeuta" width="120" height="120" />                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você está salvando imagem diretamente no banco de dados? Porque não salva na raiz do projeto e coloca no banco somente o endereço em que a imagem se encontra? Não seria mais simples?

Comment: @Marconi eu preciso que esta imagem fique armazenada no banco de dados. Eu tenho um outro projeto que faz exatamente o que estou querendo, e copiei o código de lá. O problema é que neste novo projeto a imagem não está sendo exibida, e não faço ideia por que.

Comment: Acho que a imagem dentro do registro do banco está quebrada. Você tem como conferir isso?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez como posso fazer esse tipo de verificação? Procurei sobre imagens quebradas no google e não achei conteúdo relevante.
Mas se a falha está no momento de armazenar a imagem no banco, pode ser que a falha esteja no código. 
Esse trecho de código que uso para fazer o upload para o banco.

Comment: using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                vmterapeuta.FotoPerfil.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream, vmterapeuta.FotoPerfil.ContentLength);
                                
                                Stream fileStream = vmterapeuta.FotoPerfil.InputStream;
                                byte[] fotoBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                                fileStream.Read(fotoBytes, 0, fotoBytes.Length);
                                objTerapeuta.FOTO = fotoBytes;
                            }

Comment: Já experimentou logar no banco usando uma ferramenta e fazer um `select` na tabela pra verificar o conteúdo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Sim, o conteúdo da coluna Foto está preenchido com o array de bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Estou respondendo minha própria pergunta por que consegui resolver o problema. Com isso outros poderão também obter ajuda.

Alterei a forma de fazer o upload da imagem no banco:

```
if (Request.Files.Count == 1)
                            {
                                var size = Request.Files[0].ContentLength;
                                var type = Request.Files[0].ContentType;
                                Stream fileStream = Request.Files[0].InputStream;

                                byte[] fotoBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                                fileStream.Read(fotoBytes, 0, fotoBytes.Length);

                                objTerapeuta.FOTO = fotoBytes;
                            }
```

Comment: Acho que seria interessante você atualizar sua pergunta com a forma antiga que estava sendo feito o upload da imagem. Ficou um pouco desconexo a pergunta com esta resposta.